# Can we stop Gmail from calling home to google before resolving a url?

Tags: security, gmail, firefox-for-android

When you click on a link in gmail on your phone, it first queries www.google.com with the url of your query, and then redirects to the destination URL. Is there a way to stop this "feature" of google knowing about all the URLs you click on? I've switching from chrome to firefox as a default browser, but this functionality is in the gmail app itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to long press the URL in email and open it in new tab
But I suspect you are making your data private because Google already knows the content of your email and has it cached also 
Try and use gmail on firefox with Clean URL and adguard extension installed ,although I suspect it will work but one can hope. 
 P.S. ... you can't stop a data mongering company from intruding in your privacy while using its services